# How use enum from other class in method?

Tags: swift, enums

I need to use this enum

```
final class PermissionsManager {

  enum `Type`: String {
    case notifications, calendar, reminders, camera, photosLibrary
  }
```

in other class in method.

```
private func requireAccess(from viewController: UIViewController, to type: PermissionsManager.Type, with action: Action?) {
    PermissionsManager.requireAccess(from: viewController, to: type, completion: action)
  }
```

But in this case I have error:

> Cannot convert value of type to expected argument type

Please help! How I can convey my enum to this method??

Comment: `Type` is a preserved name in Swift. Try to use a different name.

Comment: What line has the issue? What is the definition of `PermissionsManager.requireAccess(...)`?

Comment: the best to avoid is at first to rename `Type` to `PermissionType` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you used backticks, there is still a conflict at core. Replace `Type` with something else (e.g. AccessType) and this should do.

Comment: No we can use preserved names in swift if put  the name in quotation marks. And I must write `PemissionsManager.'Type'`, but I forgot it)